# Javascript Lawnchair

Tags: javascript, cordova, lawnchair

Im using lawnchair for storage in a phonegap app. Im using it to save settings as strings. I am able to save a string and retrieve it because i print it out to the console. However, once I close out the app and restart it completely the value is no longer stored and is gone. Below is the storing and saving code. Thank you for any help in advance.

```
    // save
var lazyboy = Lawnchair({name:'settings'},function(e) {
    console.log("Storage Open!");
})

lazyboy.save({key:'1', value:obj});

    // Load
lazyboy.exists("1", function(exists) {
    if (exists) {
        lazyboy.get("1", function(obj) {
            choice = obj.value.setting;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the dom.js file solved my issue.